# Facebook like count is suddenly zero

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

I found a weird bug on my (`Wordpress`) site today...
Yesterday, my likes were still there. I didn't change any code or did something whatsoever (which is why I hope and guess it's a Facebook bug), but **suddenly** I saw that my website's page has **0 (zero) likes**...

Weird, because when I check my Facebook like button's page, I can see the exact amount of like still there, but not on my like button on the website...

What could be the problem?
I checked with the `linter tool` and there are no problems at all...

Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I see that this is a known bug and that `Facebook` will fix it ASAP:

> Ibrahim Faour - Facebook Team
>
> We have a fix for this issue and it will be pushed in the next few
>   hours. We will update this report as soon as the fix is fully pushed
>   and verified.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/657504371028995/