# Facebook Like button shows that 0 people like my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Whereas more than 950 people already liked it...

If I go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button and put www.facebook.com/birdsbase in the 'URL to Like' box, it shows that 0 people liked this page. If you'd go to this URL you'd see the over 950 people have already liked it.

What went wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook like count is suddenly zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756732/facebook-like-count-is-suddenly-zero)