# Facebook like plugin suddenly showing 0 count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

The facebook like plugin counter was working fine until today. Now the plugin shows 0 likes.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=708684989223064&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/edmhuntersofficial" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

I checked with Facebook's Object Debugger and there don't seem to be any issues.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

My website's URL where it is live is [here](http://www.edmhunters.com/avicii)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook like count is suddenly zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756732/facebook-like-count-is-suddenly-zero)

Comment: @luschn Looks like it's an issue at Facebook's end

Comment: i know, you guys keep opening new threads on stackoverflow for the exact same bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue at Facebook's end. It's solved now.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the canonical tag url that count will back to zero count make sure keep canonical url same and also its case sensitive