# Facebook Developers like button "URL to Like" doesn't read my facebook page likes

Tags: facebook-like

I went to this page: "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button" and when I write my facebook page in the like button box: "https://www.facebook.com/myPlebe24.com" (with button_count) it simply doesn't show my 38 likes, instead shows the number "0" in the counter. However, when I use the Like Box, to do the same, then it shows my 38 likes.

I happens the same with the Follow Button, since the counter shows 0, when my facebook page has 38 likes.

Can someone please help me to understand what might be the issue causing this? I need the Like Button to recognize my 38 likes.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug that is happening for a lot of people right now, take a look at this thread: [Facebook like count is suddenly zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756732/facebook-like-count-is-suddenly-zero)